# Bookmarks seem to be overwriting each other

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Sometimes I think creating complex DAX queries is easier than working with bookmarks. I am not able to get an extremely simple bookmark scenario to work correctly. Here is what I am doing:

```
#1: Place a card visual on a page and set the field to a measure.
#2: Add a bookmark, rename it and update it.
#3: Create a second bookmark
#4: With the second bookmark selected (I select it by clicking on it), I change the field in the card to a different measure.
#5: I update the second bookmark (not the first).
```

When I toggle between the two bookmarks they both show the same value, the measure I used in step #4. No matter what I try I cannot get this to work correctly.

I have Data, Display, Current Page and All Visuals checked on both bookmarks.

Comment: Are you actually changing the measure used or just setting a filter that controls what measure is displayed?

Comment: I am changing the measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmarks are for setting slicers and filters as well as the state and visibility of visuals. They don't save any arbitrary configuration of your report. If you change what your underlying elements (e.g. columns, measures, or placement visuals) the bookmark doesn't "remember" what all those were; it only saves the state of certain things (which does not include what measure you put in a field).